# i dont know why when i want to convert py to exe pyinstaller is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

i use: pyinstaller main.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 424, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\PycharmProjects\untitled\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 273, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 214, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\koksem1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing os.fspath() an empty variable or 'None' somewhere.

If you pass `os.fspath()` a string, it is returned unchanged.

Otherwise `__fspath__()` is called and its value is returned as long as it is a string or bytes object. In all other cases, TypeError is raised..

```
>>> os.fspath("C:/USERS/")
'C:/USERS/'

>>> os.fspath(10)  #won't take INT
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int

>>> os.fspath(None)  #nor will it take 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```